# Выборка из двух таблиц Mysql по строке

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы в БД где ищу совпадения по полям типа VARCHAR
Когда делаю запрос

```
SELECT row1, row2, row3, row4 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

То БД подвисает. Тот же самый запрос с поиском по id выдает быстро результат. Но мне не надо по id :)

Comment: вот индексы по поставьте на эти поля.

Comment: Про индексы уже сказали. Но чтоб они работали быстрвее - подумайте, если возможность уменьшить длину этих полей VARCHAR